# PHP Sockets Errors (connection refused and No such file or directory)

Tags: php, sockets

I am writing a server app (broadcaster) and a client (relayer). Several relayers can connect to the broadcaster at the same time, send information and the broadcaster will redirect the message to a matching relayer (for example relayer1 sends to broadcaster who sends to relayer43, relayer2 -> broadcaster -> relayer73...)

The server part is working as I have tested it with a telnet client and although its at this point only an echo server it works.

Both relayer and broadcaster sit on the same server so I am using AF_UNIX sockets, both files are in different folders though.

I have tried two approaches for the relayer and both have failed, the first one is using socket_create:

```
public function __construct()
{  
    // where is the socket server?
    $this->_sHost = 'tcp://127.0.0.1';
    $this->_iPort = 11225;

    // open a client connection
    $this->_hSocket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    echo 'Attempting to connect to '.$this->_sHost.' on port '.$this->_iPort .'...';
    $result = socket_connect($this->_hSocket, $this->_sHost, $this->_iPort);
    if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($this->_hSocket)) . "\n";
    } else {
    echo "OK.\n";
```

}

This returns "Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [2]: No such file or directory in relayer.class.php on line 27" and (its running from command line) it often also returns a segmentation fault.

The second approach is using pfsockopen:

```
public function __construct()
{  
// where is the socket server?
$this->_sHost = 'tcp://127.0.0.1';
$this->_iPort = 11225;

// open a client connection  
$fp = pfsockopen ($this->_sHost, $this->_iPort, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp)
{
  $result = "Error: could not open socket connection";
}
else
{
  // get the welcome message
  fgets ($fp, 1024);
  // write the user string to the socket
  fputs ($fp, 'Message ' . __LINE__);
  // get the result
  $result .= fgets ($fp, 1024);
  // close the connection
  fputs ($fp, "END");
  fclose ($fp);
  // trim the result and remove the starting ?
  $result = trim($result);
  $result = substr($result, 2);
  // now print it to the browser
}
```

which only returns the error "Warning: pfsockopen(): unable to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:11225 (Connection refused) in relayer.class.php on line 33 "

In all tests I have tried with different host names, 127.0.0.1, localhost, tcp://127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.199, tcp://192.168.0.199, none of it has worked.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'm sure all that can be condensed to one or two lines.

Comment: perhaps, could you provide me those working lines please? as you can see I have really tried but failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently one of the firewalls was playing a role here, sorry to have wasted your time. If anyone is running into this problem check that your ports are open, it did the trick for me